# Delphi 7 - When to use .create(Application) and when to use .create(nil)?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've read a LOT of stuff lately regarding this, but never found a final answer.
So, for example if I write:

`Form1 := TForm1.Create(Application);`

the aplication should be responsible for freeing the form from memory right?
why then people usually do as follows:

```
Form1 := TForm1.Create(Application);
Form1.ShowModal;
Form1.Free;
```

??
Saw in some places that if you try to "free" an object that was already freed you would get an EAccessviolation msg, but as I tested it is not always true.

So PLEASE, How this actually works??
This EAccessviolation thing is driving me crazy, how can I understand this thing completely?? where do I find this precious information!??

Comment: There's no double free in that code. When the form is freed, it calls its owner (application) so that the application can remove it from its list of to be destroyed components.

Comment: Wait isn't the purpose of Free method to check if the object still exists and only then calling the objects default destructor? I do know that calling object destructor directly Will always cause EAccesViolation if the objects no longer exists or hasn't been created yet.

Comment: @Silver In the code in the Q Free and Destroy are interchangeable because at Form1.Free, Form1 cannot be nil. Assuming that no other party is screwing with that var. An assumption that is hard to make if you are following the Delphi IDE's VB compat mode and making Form1 a global var.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know that in the code that is shown in question the Form1 can't be nill at the time. But I'm asking in general becouse I always assign an owner to every Form that I create even thou I plan on destroying that form later on myself way before destroying its owner. And so far folowing this patter I have never gotten the EAccesViolation when owner tried to destroy already non-existant form. So I just want to know if that is acceptable approach or not.

Comment: @silver my advice is never assign an owner

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mind telling me why?

Comment: @Silver for a form, the owner is generally pointless. Explicit destruction allows you to control when it happens. For instance, a modal form might be shown many times. With a new instance every time, and owned by the main form, you have a leak.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I disagree with the fact that for a form Owner is pointless. For instance in the next scenario it can be Quite susefull. Imagine you have a second form that alows you for instance to select some product from a list. Then you might want to provide some aditional information about this product on demmand on the third form. So if later you decide to close the seconf form you would probably want to close/destroy the third form aswell since showing it alone would only make confusion becouse you won't know to which product does that aditional data belong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes you could modiffy the second form OnClose event to call Close action for the third from, but you can achieve the same simply by specifying second form to be the owner of the third form when it is created.

Comment: @Silver Pass that information in a parameter. Don't conflate that with component ownership, an unrelated thing.

Comment: @silver Owner is fine if you need the owned component to live exactly as long as the owning component. Perfect for most components on a form. But for forms themselves that is often not what you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Pass that infomration as parameter? What information do you have in mind and from where to where.

Comment: @Silver OK, I misunderstood. Sure, if you don't want to keep a reference to the other form, and you want it to be destroyed whenever the first form is destroyed, an owner is fine.

Comment: @SilverWarior In my answer that is covered by *Ownership between forms is reasonable for, say, the main form and a modeless relative that lives as long as the main form. The modeless form can be owned by the main form and then destroyed automatically when the main form is destroyed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task of a component's `Owner` is to destroy all owned components when you the owner are being destroyed.

The `Application` object is destroyed upon termination and so if you are relying on it to destroy your form, that won't happen until termination.

The key point here is the assigning an owner controls both **who** destroys the owned component, but also **when** it is destroyed.

In your case you have a modal form that you want to have a short life. Always write them like this:

```
Form := TMyModalForm.Create(nil);
try
  Form.ShowModal;
finally
  Form.Free;
end;
```

There's no point giving them an owner since you explicitly destroy it. And make sure that `Form` is a local variable.

It won't hurt particularly if you did pass an owner. It would just be wasteful as the owner was notified of its responsibility, and then notified that it was no longer responsible.

But if you did this:

```
Form := TMyModalForm.Create(Self);
Form.ShowModal;
```

then each time you showed the modal form you'd leak a form that would not be destroyed until the owning form was destroyed. If you made `Application` the owned, the modal forms would be leaked until termination.

Ownership between forms is reasonable for, say, the main form and a modeless relative that lives as long as the main form. The modeless form can be owned by the main form and then destroyed automatically when the main form is destroyed.

But if the main form holds a reference to the modeless form then I'd probably just have it unowned and explicitly destroyed from the main form's destructor.

@dummzeuch makes the good point that if you set `Position` to `poOwnerFormCenter`, then the framework expects you to provide a form as the owner. In my view, this is a poor design which conflates lifetime management with visual layout. But that is the design, so you are compelled to go along with it. There is though nothing to stop you explicitly destroying an owned component. You can do this:

```
Form := TMyModalForm.Create(Self); // Self is another form
try
  Form.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
  Form.ShowModal;
finally
  Form.Free;
end;
```

When you destroy the form, its owner is notified, and the destroyed form is removed the owner's list of owned components.

The main form itself is interesting. It has to be owned by `Application` since the main form has to be created by calling `Application.CreateForm`. That's the only time you should call `Application.CreateForm`. And the main form is usually the only form you should have owned by `Application`. Especially if you adopt the policy of having other forms unowned, or owned by the forms that spawn them.

But if you let the main form be destroyed at termination, when `Application` is destroyed, then you can bee caught out. I've experienced intermittent runtime errors at termination when coded that way. My remedy is to explicitly destroy the main form as the final act of the main .dpr file's body. That is, destroy the main form after `Application.Run` returns.

Comment: There is another issue which nobody has mentioned yet: TForm.Position allows you to specify where the form will be positioned when you open it. It has one possible value poOwnerFormCenter which supposedly centres the form on the owner form. If you pass NIL, it can't. But what does it do if you pass Application?

Comment: It uses `TCustomForm(Owner)` if `Owner is TCustomForm`, otherwise it uses `Application.MainForm`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  In the project  i'm working with, I was using `Application.CreateForm` for the data module also. After I saw your post I tried to modify it acording to your example, and I got a new Eaccessviolation exception. Any guesses why?

Comment: OK, data modules are rather beyond my area of expertise. I never use them, not really my style. However, I believe that you should be able to create data modules without using `CreateForm`. However, typically you want a data module because you expose it globally to all and sundry. So perhaps if you used a local variable for the dm rather than a global variable you would have problems. Anyway, it's a little hard for me to say from here without seeing more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well sir, now I'm curious.. I know the complete explanation would be to extensive, but in short, what do you use then?
Having so much trouble with this Eaccessviolation thing lately that in my new projects I wanna keep global variables to as few as possible, exactly the oposite of a dm...

Comment: Lots of reasons for access violations. Perhaps it's not caused by what you think it is caused? I personally don't use data modules because I regard them to be a rather poor form of design. Encourages lots of coupling and makes it hard to layer.

Comment: Data modules are the other exception to the global IDE-created variables and auto-create forms, particularly when the datamodule needs to be accessed from the main form. In that case, leave the global variable for the datamodule, and use Project->Options->Forms to move the datamodule above the main form in the Auto-create list. Datamodules cannot be the main form, so it's safe to create them first.

Answer (score 11):

The general rules are:

- If you're going to free it yourself, use `nil` as the owner.
- If you're not going to free it yourself, assign an owner that will take the responsibility to free it.

So, if your code is something like this:

```
Form1 := TForm1.Create(...)
Form1.ShowModal;
Form1.Free;
```

You should write it with `nil` as the owner, and protect it in a try..finally block:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm: TForm2;
begin
  AForm := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    AForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    AForm.Free;  // You know when it will be free'd, so no owner needed
  end;
end;
```

If on the other hand, you're going to leave it around for a while, assign an owner that can take care of freeing it later:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm: TForm2;
begin
  AForm := TForm2.Create(Application);
  // Here you don't know when it will be free'd, so let the
  // Application do so
  AForm.Show;
end;
```

Neither of these techniques will cause an access violation if done the way I've demonstrated here. Note that in both cases, I did not use the IDE-generated `Form2` variable, but used a local one instead to avoid confusion. Those IDE-generated variables are evil (except for the required `Form1` or whatever you name it that represents the main form, which must be auto-created and owned by the Application). Other than the var for the main form, I always delete that auto-generated variable immediately, and never auto-create anything except possibly a datamodule (which can be autocreated before the main form without any problem, as a datamodule cannot be the main form).

Comment: Ken can you expand on your answer? I would like to know why you do not prefer the auto-generated / IDE-generated variables?

Comment: In the context of memory-managment, using Application as owner is pointless. Owner frees the owned objects when it is destroyed and since the Application object will be destroyed when the program exits, in the sense you still have a memory leak. When program exits, all memory will be freed anyway, so using Application as owner doesn't make difference.

Comment: Everything is already said by "assign an owner that will take the responsibility to free it."

Comment: Leaving forms as owned by Application can result in leaks, as @ain said.

Comment: @RawN: The IDE generated variable names are global, which is always something to be avoided. Global variables can cause all sorts of problems, such as leading you to access something you didn't intend, freeing something you didn't want to free, or thinking you've freed something you didn't. Variable scopes should be as limited as possible, and global variables are almost always a horrible idea. Because of the way Delphi applications work, it's required that the main form be auto-created and global. I remove the others for the above reasons.

Comment: @KenWhite: I agree.  I delete the blasted form variables as soon as the IDE creates them.  Otherwise I find some of my developers using them from other forms to access controls within !!  Also, if you are allowing multiple copies of a form then one variable is not going to help.